# RDS to light sail database migration

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-lightsail

**Migrate large postgres RDS to light sail database.**
Have tried using pg_dump but it takes some time.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)